# How to add export functionality to custom button in React highcharts?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, export, react-highcharts

I have this project in which I am trying to implement export highchart functionality from out side of the chart.

Is there any way I can achieve that? I am using React highcharts and the download formats are Jpeg and CSV.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by exporting highchart functionality from outside?

Comment: downloading the JPEG, CSV of highchart from buttons which are outside of chart area.

Comment: So basically, there is the export module of highchart, which provides us a menu button and different functionality of downloads like JPEG, SVG, PDF. I am trying to achieve the same thing but from outside of chart. Are there any events which can help me with this?

Comment: Hi @abhishek gangwar, Do you use the officially supported wrapper for React? https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official

Comment: Did you figure it out? Having the same issue right now... can't find the getCSV() method on the Chart object, even if the context button works well and download a proper csv

Comment: @Yannick, I cannot find this method either on the chart object. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 7):

I found an solution using functional components:

First import the modules:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';

require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/modules/export-data')(Highcharts);
```

Then create a ref to the chart:

```
  const chart = useRef();
....
....
<HighchartsReact ref={chart} highcharts={Highcharts} options={chartOptions} />
```

Then create a method like this one, triggered by a click event:

```
  const downloadCSV = () => {
    if (chart && chart.current && chart.current.chart) {
      chart.current.chart.downloadCSV();
    }
  };
```

Comment: I get an `Uncaught TypeError: chart.current.chart.downloadPNG is not a function`. Why could this be?

Comment: Well downloadCSV was my example. To download the image, I used  chart.current.chart.exportChart()

Answer (score 0):

From @Yannick response... This works for me.

```
const chart = useRef(null);  <-------- important
....
....
<HighchartsReact ref={chart} highcharts={Highcharts} options={chartOptions} />
```