# How can I add a full screen button in HighchartsReact?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts

I am using [HighchartsReact](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react) and want to add a button that allows me to toggle full screen mode that is not in the exporting menu, like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1ga2fqL0/).

I have found [this](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=42542) help topic documentation but it appears I cannot access `Highcharts.Chart.prototype.toggleFullscreen()` method in `HighchartsReact`.

I have also found this that I can import:

`import HighchartsFullscreen from 'highcharts/modules/full-screen';`

But there does not seem to be any information on what it does anywhere on the internet.

I cannot find any other documentation on how to do this.

What is the correct way to handle this if at all possible?

#### Update

I have followed the example from the third comment below but am getting the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: chart.current.chart.downloadSVG is not a function`

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=29073&__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=7b5ab811d9f2889616c3dbc230ac2ed1e2f67743-1579788781-0-AZyvZvpbQC2Ma3Ll9uw0nG1FVQrcBuqPIA25D0Sd8acog7AKU0TIMSF_P9QhsfHVgScRFCFWWks-9Yqo2tcOUl3bsDPIXN0AO2TfFplVSR_oe2KRvmjB78pM-frSK0IO7lAaK5rRIS9JBB5tqFe1ZT3NF5VhB4rP0-U6lN3RvuEkQIM15DXMm6wVWzwIRc9Iw9RbIyqu9e_Wz-gHP9TLY1dAEdx73yVPIU5L8r01ui-IDLERrsdZUMmkWZCEr-QRsWCkJUmH7B-CKmiOARZTWFytlOS_eV1xjh51St_HfK0jgL-Vnrqwz3NqkhVQnKgZBP2WhXbRUIhnU_berONsklkEtnB5heBRKcEcpb9g6Up2

Comment: Thanks, yes, I don't want the button in the exporting menu.

Comment: Ho ok ! Then maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58098067/how-to-add-export-functionality-to-custom-button-in-react-highcharts

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question above.

Answer (score 4):

HighCharts React - Export Button Customization / Adding a custom export button.

Here you go,

```
//HighCharts
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'

require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/modules/export-data')(Highcharts);

const Chart = () =>
{
    const chart = useRef();

const exportHandler = (type) => 
  {
    if (chart && chart.current && chart.current.chart) 
    {
      switch (type) 
      {
        case "png":
          chart.current.chart.exportChart();
          break;

        case "jpeg":
          chart.current.chart.exportChart({type: 'image/jpeg'});
          break;

        case "svg":
          chart.current.chart.exportChart({type: 'image/svg+xml'});
          break;

        case "pdf":
          chart.current.chart.exportChart({type: 'application/pdf'});
          break;

        case "csv":
          chart.current.chart.downloadCSV();
          break;

        case "xls":
          chart.current.chart.downloadXLS();
          break;

        case "table":
          chart.current.chart.toggleDataTable();
          break;

        case "fullScreen":
          chart.current.chart.fullscreen.toggle()

          break;

        case "print":
          chart.current.chart.print();
          break;
      
        default:
          break;
      }      
    }
  };
    
    return(
     <>
        <HighchartsReact
          highcharts={Highcharts}

          ref={chart}
        />

     <button onClick = {() => exportHandler('png')}>Custom Export</buttnon
    </>
    )
}

export default Chart;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the `exporting` module and call:

```
new Highcharts.FullScreen(chart.container);
```

---

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4766/

**Example with React**: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-lyd8z

Comment: Thanks very much for this and great to know it works! This is throwing errors for me - to begin with I am using a function component so I get the linter throwing `Do not use 'new' for side effects.eslint(no-new)` but I know that I just have to assign the new instantiation to a variable to fix this.

Second, as I am using TypeScript I get `Property 'FullScreen' does not exist on type 'typeof import(".../node_modules/highcharts/highcharts")'.` Also `this` is obviously redundant too.

Any ideas here? Thanks